# Object Mapper result window shows no objects although 13 items were found

Tags: db4o

I installed the Db4o VS plugin and connected to a local source.
When I right-click my class in the db4o browser window and choose "Show all objects" the rsult window pops up with the text "No. of Objects Retrieved: 13" but none are shown.

Creating and running a custom query gives the same result.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you send us a simple db/assembly that reproduces this behavior? You can email me direct: adriano at db4o (the rest you already know :))

Comment: gladly done. Hope it'll help you (and in the end me) out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked the database/assemblies you sent me.

There are two aspects contributing to this issue:

- A know limitation of OME (related to Gamlor suggestion): If you have enums stored in your db you need to configure OME so it will be able to find the enum type definition. To do that just do as user Gamlor said, i.e, in VS just go to Tools/Object Manager Enterprise/Options/Assembly Search Path... and add the folders where your assemblies can be found (See pictures bellow)

[image: OMN Options]

[image: OMN Assembly search path]

After you configure your assembly search path OMN will display your objects correctly. Unfortunately once your assembly gets loaded into VS the only way to unload it is by restarting VS.

- Exception handling in OMN has some quirks that need to be improved. In this case when OMN tries to show objects for which it needs the actual types to be present but it fails to find these types, an exception is thrown but at a higher level it is caught (and logged to a file under "\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\db4objects\ObjectManagerEnterprise\ExceptionLogXXXX.log" where XXXX is a number) but the user is not notified.

Hope this helps.

Best

Comment: Thanks, your help is highly appreciated. I will check this out one of the following evenings.

Answer (score 2):

Which Version are you using? The object manager which is shipped with 7.12? Or the one with the 8.0 betas?

Maybe adding the assemblies with your class-model helps: Goto "Tools" -> "Object Manager Enterprise" -> "Options"->"Assembly Search Path..." and add your assemblies. However the OME will lock the assemblies, so maybe better use a copy.

Another question: Are you using any type-handler? I thing currently the OME cannot deal with database which were created using custom typehandlers.

Comment: I'm using the one from the 8 betas because it's the only one working with VS2010. Adding the assemblies doesn't seem to change the situation. I don't know what type handlers are so I figure I haven't used any ;)